# Get massive compile error whenever windows.h is included, my environment is visual studio 2013 in win 7

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors, windows-7

I have a CPP file Log.cpp which has one line code:

```
    #include "windows.h"
```

When I compile it, massive syntax errors display:

```
    1>------ Build started: Project: topx, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
    1>  Log.cpp
    1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\winbase.h(936): error C2065: 'hMem' : undeclared identifier
    1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\winbase.h(936): error C2065: 'dwBytes' : undeclared identifier
    1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\winbase.h(938): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\winbase.h(938): error C2491: '_Ret_reallocated_bytes_' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
    1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\winbase.h(938): error C2078: too many initializers
    1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\winbase.h(938): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'HGLOBAL'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\winbase.h(938): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '__stdcall'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\winbase.h(938): error C2377: 'HGLOBAL' : redefinition; typedef cannot be overloaded with any other symbol
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\minwindef.h(211) : see declaration of 'HGLOBAL'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\winbase.h(940): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'hMem'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\winbase.h(940): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
    1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\winbase.h(940): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\winbase.h(943): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
    ....
    ....
```

But all is OK when I compile it under windows 8, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared
```

to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared
```

in "Additional include directories" of project resolve this problem, but I do not know why.